# Set cursor position in a UITextField (Monotouch)

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, cursor, uitextfield

In a UITextField used for entering decimal numbers I would like to get rid of possible leading zeros (The behavior should be like the one of the Calculator App). Normally this would be rather easy to implement but I just cannot figure out how to restore the cursor position.

UITextField has a property SelectedTextRange of type UITextRange which can be used to get the cursor position. However, there seems no easy way to get the current index nor to create a new UITextRange object that contains the new values.

I could find the solution in objective c: [Finding the cursor position in a UITextField](http://neofight.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/finding-the-cursor-position-in-a-uitextfield/)
It is however very unclear to me how to rewrite that in Monotouch. Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like MonoTouch (at least the 5.3 alpha I'm looking now) is not exposing every methods in `UITextField` (and `UITextView`), in particular those that comes from `UITextInput` (but the properties are there).

This means that methods like `GetPosition` are presently missing - which makes it hard to duplicate the code from the link you provided.

**UPDATE** It was a bug where `UITextInput` methods were not added to `UITextField` and `UITextView`. This will be fixed in the next releases. IOW the next stable release, 5.2.11, will have the missing methods.

Comment: Thanks for your message! Let's hope that they really add it in the next stable version. It cannot be that trivial things like that are not available in Monotouch...